# Can't delete my own questions in Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app

If was pointed out to me that one of my questions was a duplicate, so I went to delete it. No such option available?

Comment: Did the question have an accepted or positively scored answer?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The vast majority of duplicate questions provide no additional visibility and can just be deleted.  It's really only a rare few that really add value though improved searchability.

Comment: @hichris123 Gah, you beat me by 12 seconds :P

Comment: @Doorknob Silly doorknob, you should know humans are better at finding duplicates than door(knob)s! :P

Comment: @Servy, none, just a few comments (one pointing to the duplicate)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, just a few comments, hardly a minute had gone by.

Comment: @vonbrand, depends on the effort you put in that question, then. (I personally still do not believe in deleting duplicates, though ;)

Comment: This thread got derailed to be about whether or not a single post should be deleted. This is a reasonable feature request to have the delete option in the app.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I understand all that very well. It was more of as case of "oops, silly question, already much better asked".